# How to "unkeep" classes in Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

My proguard has

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```

I'm after a rule that would keep all activities but those marked with my "Obfuscateable" interface:

```
 public class SensitiveActivity extends Activity implements Obfuscateable
```

Is there a negative rule so Proguard keeps all the activities (first rule) minus those marked with interface Obfuscateable? I mean, like the opposite of "keep"?

In the related manual section http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html there's a template for class specifications, but I can't understand it very well:

```
[@annotationtype] [[!]public|final|abstract|@ ...] [!]interface|class|enum classname
    [extends|implements [@annotationtype] classname]
[{
    [@annotationtype] [[!]public|private|protected|static|volatile|transient ...] <fields> |
                                                                      (fieldtype fieldname);
    [@annotationtype] [[!]public|private|protected|static|synchronized|native|abstract|strictfp ...] <methods> |
                                                                                           <init>(argumenttype,...) |
                                                                                           classname(argumenttype,...) |
                                                                                           (returntype methodname(argumenttype,...));
    [@annotationtype] [[!]public|private|protected|static ... ] *;
    ...
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProGuard always considers the union of all -keep options; there are no options to subtract from it. You can mark activities that you want to *keep* with a marker interface or an annotation (e.g. proguard/examples/annotations).

The Android build process (aapt) automatically writes out a ProGuard configuration that keeps all exported activities, so you may have to modify that, after it has been generated and before ProGuard is called.

Comment: at the end i found a simpler way!! I noticed that Proguard does obfuscate activities that are not public by default, so I just create package activities with all the logic, and public activities that just extend the package one and little more. This way I get 100% of the logic obfuscated and repackaged, and the activities are just little stubs ! Also, the set*** methods get renamed from the package activities downwards, which contributes a lot to the obfuscation chaos :)